# How to have hidden folders in a git repo

Tags: git, build, automated-tests

I have a need to add a test code to git repositories but have not test code not visible to some user's of the repositories. How can I do this?

I have repositories that are consumed (read only) by other teams. The other teams include all files in the repository into a installer. I cannot change those build processes, as they are outside of my sphere of influence. But, I have a need to add tests to the repositories without the test code being consumed in other teams the build process. So I think I want to add folders to a repository but make these new folder hidden to some users.

**More detail ...**

The repositories have a very long history and have active work in multiple release branches. As features are different in different release branches and are being worked on in developer branches I need the tests to be in the same repo so they are branch specific. Well .... that is my assumption.

Like most problems I cannot find a solution to maybe my assumptions here are wrong. I've tried placing my tests in another branch and the build system works fine if we are careful to keep branch names identical in both repos ... but that is difficult.

So as a perceived possible solution I was wondering if I could either filter what some users see, or create a 'mirror' repo that is a subset of the source repo.

Hope I have explained the problem. Ideas?

Comment: You can't hide folders in git.

Comment: Yea the title is about capturing a problem rather than the perceived solution. I thought that was the case ... I'm looking for a solution that is 'effectively' the "same as".

Comment: Your best option (my opinion), which is bad, is that you could have a public version of your repository, and a private version. You would merge the public repo into your private one if you changes the public, but you would aways have to be 100% aware of which repo you're in and which repo you're **supposed** to be in. If you, instead, create a filter-branch approach, you will get completely different hashes so when the consumers of your filtered repo says "We're having problems with commit #28949827...", you're going to have to look at the filtering to figure out which private commit that is.

Comment: How about the consumers of your repository gets the whole repository and just makes sure their build process only uses the right parts? Also, why is their build process consuming your source code? Is there no way to publish ready-built components from your repository that they could consume instead?

Comment: Yes Lasse, your right, but as I said that is outside my sphere of influence ... in other words it is not going to happen. Same about the read-built, that is my end goal.